# Delete or Replace nth line in a file after a pattern match using shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I need to replace 11th line after the pattern match "msq_Query" in a file, the original text should remain intact. 
A one-liner sed or awk would be helpful !!

```
*msq_Query
{
    { BaconOutput1, 0419000000, 0144567891,
        <
        OIN ,
        TIN ,
        BPARTY
        >
    ,
        <
        >
    , 1477361456, 0}
}
```

In the 11th line in the file, number (whihc could be random) should be replaced by 0 
OR 
11th line should be deleted .

Comment: your title says "after a pattern match", but your question doesn't specify what pattern you want to match. Please update your question with details for what should be matched, and what rules to apply for "Delete or Replace Nth line after". Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this would be with awk like this:

```
awk -v lines=11 'BEGIN { ignore = -1 } /pattern/ { ignore = NR + lines } NR != ignore { print }' filename
```

Substitute `pattern` with your own pattern.

This works as follows:

```
BEGIN { ignore = -1 }             # initialize ignore with -1 so NR will never
                                  # be equal to it by accident

/pattern/ { ignore = NR + lines } # when the pattern is found, set ignore to the
                                  # line we want to ignore

NR != ignore { print }            # unless the current line is that line, print
                                  # it.
```

In order to replace something in the line instead of deleting it, the script can be amended as follows:

```
awk -v lines=11 'BEGIN { mark = -1 } /pattern/ { mark = NR + lines } NR == mark { sub(/[0- 9]+/, "") } { print }' filename
```

that is:

```
BEGIN { mark = -1 }                # initialize mark with -1 so NR will never
                                   # be equal to it by accident

/pattern/ { mark = NR + lines }    # when the pattern is found, set mark to the
                                   # line we want to ignore

NR == mark { sub(/[0-9]+/, "0"); } # if that line is the current line, substitute
                                   # stuff (stuff can be freely chosen)

{ print }                          # print all the lines.
```

Comment: You don't have to set ignore to -1. You can't have a record of 0 so it doesn't matter.Also it won't even exist before you set it so there is no chance of a mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way i can think of

`delete`

```
awk '/pattern/{x=12}x--!=1' file
```

'replace'

```
awk '/pattern/{x=12}x--==1{$0="REPLACEMENT"}1' file
```

Comment: Why have the comments been deleted ?

Answer (score 0):

My take:
`sed '/msq_Query/,+11 {1,11n;s/1477361456/1234/}' file`

explanation:

```
/msq_Query/,+11 --> take block starting with the line mathing 'msq_Query' and the next 11 lines
{ ... }         --> on that 12-line block execute the commands within curly braces, which are:
1,11n           --> skip lines 1 through 11
s/old/new/      --> in the remainder of the block substitute 'old' with 'new'
```

I used this file as test:

```
*msq_Query
{
    { BaconOutput1, 0419000000, 0144567891,
        <
        OIN ,
        TIN ,
        BPARTY
        >
    ,
        <
        >
    , 1477361456, 0}
}
1477361456
*msq_Query
{
    { BaconOutput1, 0419000000, 0144567891,
        <
        OIN ,
        TIN ,
        BPARTY
        >
    ,
        <
        >
    , 1477361456, 0}
}
1477361456
```

and the `sed` command turned it into

```
*msq_Query
{
    { BaconOutput1, 0419000000, 0144567891,
        <
        OIN ,
        TIN ,
        BPARTY
        >
    ,
        <
        >
    , 1234, 0}
}
1477361456
*msq_Query
{
    { BaconOutput1, 0419000000, 0144567891,
        <
        OIN ,
        TIN ,
        BPARTY
        >
    ,
        <
        >
    , 1234, 0}
}
1477361456
```